# Prove a group of order $p(p+q)$ is not simple for primes $p$ and $q$ where $ p \geq q$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, simple-groups

So my question is the title; I have been self studying for an exam coming up and this problem showed up. I am not sure how to proceed I can't seem to see how the $n_p(G)$ is related to $p+q$. Any hint is appreciated! Also, I have already finished the case when $p=q$.

EDIT: If $p=q$ then $G$ is of order $2p^2$. Now, if $p=2$, then $|G|=8$. Up to isomorphism we have 5 groups of order $8$ all of which are not simple. So we may suppose that $p$ is an odd prime. In this case every Sylow $p$-subgroup has index two in $G$ and thus is normal. So we may suppose that $q<p$....

Comment: What did you find in the case $p=q$?  Include your solution in that case within your post.

Comment: Sorry about that. I edited the post, hopefully I did it correctly.

Comment: Thanks, E.C., I appreciate that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that $p > q$. Then we have that $\gcd(p,p+q)=\gcd(p,q) = 1$

Hence by Sylow Theorems we have that $n_p(G) \equiv 1 \pmod p$. Also $n_p(G) \mid p+q$. But now $n_p(G) \le p+q < 2p < 2p+1$. Moreover $p+1 \not \mid p+q$, as $p+2 < p+q < 2p+2$. Therefore we must have that $n_p(G) = 1$. Hence the proof.

---

As $n_p(G) \equiv 1 \pmod p$ we must have that $n_p(G) = kp+1$ for some non-negative integer $k$. From above we have that $kp+1 = n_p(G) < 2p+1$ and so we have that $k<2$. The case $k=1$ is impossible, as $p+1 \not \mid p+q$ and hence we must have $k=0$. Hence the proof.

Comment: I am sorry, I don't seem to understand how you can infer that $n_p(G)$ is $1$ based of that previous inequality.

Comment: @E.C. I added a further explanation above. Hopefully everything is clear now.

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you!